# jQuery focus / blur $_GET['variable'] conflict

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple focus / blur.  'Name of Venue' is shown by default since it's the value of the input type.  on 'focus' it hides and on 'blur' is shows again if there's no text.

Here's the input field

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="search_name" value="Name of Venue" maxlength="100" />
```

Here's the jQuery

```
$('#search_name').focus(function() {
  if($(this).val() == 'Name of Venue') {
    $(this).val('');
  }
});

$('#search_name').blur(function() {
  if($(this).val() == '') {
    $(this).val('Name of Venue');
  }
});
```

On submit I don't want 'Name of Venue' to be stored as the get variable for `$_GET['name']`.  So, I'm doing  `<br /><br />` PHP

```
if($_GET['name'] === 'Name of Venue') {
  $_GET['name'] = '';
}
```

But, this doesn't work. How can I make it so the get variable will be empty on submit if it's the default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the HTML5 [placeholder](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) attribute if possible. The value will be blank if nothing was entered.

```
<input type="text" name="search_name" id="search_name" placeholder="Name of Venue" maxlength="100" />
```

It will appear/disappear automatically, so you won't need the focus/blur code. Also, "name" is a bad name for  `name`, I'd use something more unique (usually the `id` will do).

As an alternative, you could do this:

```
<form id="myform" method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="search_name" id="search_name" value="Name of Venue" maxlength="100" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // ready() not need if <script> follows content, but best to put this in a .js file and link in <head>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Define once and you're good
        var search_name = $('#search_name');
        var submit_button = $('#submit_button');
        var search_default = 'Name of Venue';

        search_name.focus(function() {
            if($(this).val() == search_default) {
                $(this).val('');
            }
        });

        search_name.blur(function() {
            if($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).val(search_default);
            }
        });

        $("#myform").submit(function(event) {
            if (search_name.val() == '' || search_name.val() == search_default) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<?php
    var_dump($_GET);
    $name = '';
    if (isset($_GET['search_name'])) {
        // Without the check, we might run query when none exists
        $name = $_GET['search_name'];
        $name = $name != 'Name of Venue' ? $name : '';
    }
    var_dump($name);
?>
```

This will prevent a submit with a blank or default name. It's probably handy to put any repeated logic in a function and call those when handling the GET in PHP with any extra search variables.

Comment: Any possible solution for non HTML5 though?

Comment: Also cleaned it up a bit as well.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Make sure to use your own jQuery path :)

Comment: Also a great post: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text

Comment: That doesn't work... it still outputs '?search_name=Name+of+Venue' in the url.  I see what you're trying to do though.  For some reason it wont re-write the get variable in the server side or client side scripting if it's set to a certain value.

Comment: Good article, I'll try that out

Comment: Try this version, uses `.submit`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make the field value blank before submitting the form if value is `Name of Venue`.

```
$('#frName').submit(function() {  if($('#search_name').val() == 'Name of Venue' ){ $('#search_name').val('') } return false;});
```

You can remove return false if you want to submit the value. [Hope its helps you](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Answer (score 0):

You can control the value on client side and if it's a required field don't let the form to be submitted. If it's not required, just set the value to "" if it is "Name of Venue".